# Using Angular multiple outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-auxiliary-routes

My app-routing.module.ts content looks like this.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' }
  , { path: 'navbar/:moduleId', component: NavMenuComponent }
  , { path: 'entitylist/:menuItemId', component: EntityListComponent, outlet:"content"}
  , { path: 'profile/:profileId', component: ProfileMasterComponent}
];
```

I have a header.html. which loads header links.

```
**header.html**
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li *ngFor="let module of modules">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" [routerLink]="['/navbar',module.id]" (click)="moduleId = module.Id">
        {{module.name}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid content">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>


**nav-menu.html**
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
        <a [routerLink]="['',{outlets:{content:['entitylist',menuItem.id]}}]">{{menuItem.name}}</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Question 1

On click in any header link, it correctly loads the nav-menu.html (the side bar). However on click of any link in nav-menu.html, I want the `entity-list component` to be loaded in area (with blue border) which is right adjacent to side bar. However that does not happen. There are no errors in the console as well.

### Question 2

Once content in loaded in blue border area, I want everything to be loaded in that area only. example, I have link in `entity-list component` which should load new component, I want that new component to be loaded in blue border area only.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i think this is a matter of route design.

check this stackblitz and hope you find some idea:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-outlets-sic3d3?file=app%2Fapp.routing.ts

Comment: @pauljosephatey, I am not very well versed with router.  Functionality wise, the solution you have provided is what I need. Now I am trying it in my solution. Thank you so much for your efforts to put out the solution.